# Strange "JPEG datastream contains no image" with PHP

Tags: php, curl

I am getting a remote image and checking the size of it.

Sometimes I get a strange error saying `JPEG datastream contains no image` and I narrowed it down that it's happening at this step, in fact it's happening EXACTLY at `imagecreatefromstring`. What could be the problem? An issue with the image? Or do I need to increase some kind of memory setting in php.ini or..?

```
function ranger($url) {
    $headers = array(
        "Range: bytes=0-32768"
    );

    $curl = curl_init($url);

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $data = curl_exec($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    return $data;
}

$url = $prod['IMAGE1'];
$raw1 = ranger($url);
$im = imagecreatefromstring($raw1);
$width = imagesx($im);
$height = imagesy($im);
```

Comment: Most likely your `$data` variable does not contain an image as you expect, but only an HTML document or text error message from the remote server. Check the contents of that variable, and also what `curl_error` says.

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow these three steps to solve your problem:

1. As the error message clearly states, you do not have an image. You need to determine why you do not have an image. You could start by running `var_dump($raw1)` but you could take a look at the algorithm in general. After this step you should know why you do not have an image where you expected one.
2. ?
3. User a valid image resource as a parameter of `imagecreatefromstring`.